# Como inserir estas informações no banco de dados mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, web-service

```
$pegacodigos    = mysql_query("SELECT CODIGO FROM imovel"); 
while($codigo = mysql_fetch_array($pegacodigos){ ...
```

***Apagando e escrevendo tudo denovo:***

- O `$pegacodigos` através de um loop pega todos os `CODIGO` na tabela `IMOVEL`
- Guarda como `array` para percorrer este script http://pastebin.com/MPd3cS9C
- Começa a selecionar no web-service todas as fotos para `$codigo['CODIGO']`
- E começa a inserir no banco segundo script campos conforme imagem anexada

Isto http://pastebin.com/MPd3cS9C faz exatamente o que quero mas demora demais a ponto de eu saber que ele nunca vai conseguir executar a tarefa que eu preciso.

Para mim, tenho comigo que o `loop` está no lugar errado fazendo com que para cada foto que ele recupere, ele faça 1 conexão no web-service ou fazendo mais loops do que o necessário. O `$res` que é resultado da `$array` com `$client` retorna as 55mil fotos, o `while` tá abraçando tudo, então tem algum problema ai provocando a extrema lerdeza.

Me ajudem a descobrir o erro da lógica?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual finalidade do Soap para este array?

Comment: A finalidade dele é fazer a conexão e dar acesso a todos os dados relacionados a cada imóvel que ficam nesse servidor distante.

Answer (score 2):

eu tenho a impressão que a cada entrada no webservice, você esta pegando todas as imagens. Eu faria um teste tipo:

- tirar o while
- informar um código manualmente (linha 13)
- fazer um var_dump(ou print_r) do $res e copiar o resultado
- repetir o processo com outro código

ai você compara os resultados das duas consultas do webservice, vejas se estão listando as mesmas coisas

### Adendo ao comentário do autor

eu tentaria com outro código para comparar, pois se tratando de imagens, 55 mil registros por código me parece muito.segue abaixo uma alternativa de insert

> substituir das linhas 27 até 36

```
$sql = array(); 
foreach( $data as $row ) {
    $c = $res[$j]['Codigo'];
    $d = $res[$j]['Foto'];
    $e = $res[$j]['Thumbnail'];
    $sql[] = "('{$codigo['CODIGO']}', '{$c}', '{$d}', '{$e}')";
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO imagens (IMOVEL, CODIGO, IMAGEM_G, IMAGEM_P) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: Eu fiz o teste com apenas um código de forma manual e ele me retorna todas as imagens referentes aquele código.